# Lifetime of string literal and lifetimes invariance

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, lifetime-scoping, reference-lifetimes

I have the following code:

```
fn foo<'a>(s1: &mut &'a str, s2: &'a str) {
   *s1 = s2
}

let mut x: &'static str = "Hello";
let y = String::from("World");

foo(&mut x, &y);
```

There is a compiler error at the last line of code:

```
error[E0597]: y does not live long enough
```

As I understand it, this happens because both arguments references in the function signature have the same lifetime specified, and the compiler interprets the lifetime of the second argument reference as `'static` automatically, but its referent actual lifetime is not static.

Also, as I know, the string literals have the `'static` lifetime by default, and, for me, this means that it doesn't matter if I specify an explicit `&'static str` type for string literal or not.

But, in my example, if I remove the explicit type (`&'static str`) for `x`, this code will compile ok.

Answer (score 2):

You state *"Also, as I know, the string literals have the `'static` lifetime by default, and, for me, this means that it doesn't matter if I specify an explicit `&'static str` type for string literal or not."* but there is a subtle difference.

When you specify the type of `x` with it's lifetime, the compiler can't chose any other lifetime for `x`.

When you don't specify the lifetime the compiler is free to pick any lifetime, it can shorten the `'static` lifetime of the string literal<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html)</sup> so that the lifetime in `x` fit's the lifetime of `y` and so it can choose lifetimes that pass the borrow checker.

---

<sup>1: shared references are [variant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html) in the lifetime</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! You provided simple and very helpful explanation for me!